# Will dead network hardware still show up in Ubuntu ifconfig?

Tags: ubuntu, ifconfig

I have an Intel NUC and I suspect the onboard ethernet port died, but I'm surprised it still shows up in Ubuntu as eth0 in ifconfig. Is this behavior to be expected, or should I suspect some other source for me ethernet death?

Comment: depends on exactly in what way it is "dead". if its only mostly dead, and can respond to polls asking whether it exists, but is otherwise unable to do anything, it may appear. In your specific case, I would bet the chipset itself is reporting that its there, because it should be, without having checked itself. Nics are usually PCI/PCIE devices, so the system accesses them through the southbridge.

Comment: It was plugged into the router, was working fine, and then I woke it from suspension and it wasn't anymore. I can plug a different computer into the same router port with the same ethernet cable and get online with a wired internet connection (and see eth0 as up and running with a DHCP IP address). I've tried restarting the computer and the router, and booting from USB instead of the hard drive to no avail. I suppose I now need to learn what kinds of "dead" there are, and how to describe, define, and identify them.

Comment: I've installed the Windows 10 Technical Preview and that also claims the ethernet network cable is unplugged/disconnected, so it looks to me like the answer to my question is "Yes".